# Validation based on dropdown value selected in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following values in my dropdown : AX, CA, DC, TS, TP, VI

There is one textbox. Based on dropdown value selected validation must be there, i.e, if I select TP it may allow null/blank but for other values it must not be blank.

How can I achieve this?

```
if ($("#txtCreditCardCvvNo" + i).val().length > 0) {
            if ($("#ddlCreditCardType" + i).val() == 'AX') {
                if ($("#txtCreditCardCvvNo" + i).val().length < 4) {
                    $("#err_cvvno" + i).html('CVV No. should be 4 digit');
                    status = 0;
                }

                else {
                    $("#err_cvvno" + i).html('');
                    status = 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                if ($("#txtCreditCardCvvNo" + i).val().length < 3) {
                    $("#err_cvvno" + i).html('CVV No. should be 3 digit');
                    status = 0;
                }
                else {
                    $("#err_cvvno" + i).html('');
                    status = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it's very easy to do, but please share some of your relevant code first

Comment: Have you ever tried some methods ?

Comment: Use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfNot]` or similar validation attribute (or write your own) so you get both client and server side validation

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');
select.addEventListener("change", handleSelectChange);

function handleSelectChange(e){
    switch(e.target.value){
        case: 'AX':
            inputValidationAX();
            break;
        case: 'CA':
            inputValidationCA();
            break;
        case: 'DC':
            inputValidationDC();
            break;
        case: 'TS':
            inputValidationTS();
            break;
        case: 'TP':
            inputValidationTP();
            break;
        case: 'VI':
            inputValidationVI();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom validation on change. This is based on unobstrusive validation.

```
$('select').change(function()
{
    var selectedValue= $(this).val();
    if(selectedValue=="TP")
    {
        $("#textboxId").rules("remove");
    }
    else
    {
       $("#textboxId").rules("add", "required");
    }
});
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $("#textbox").attr("required", "required");
    if($(this).val()=="TP") $("#textbox").removeAttr("required");
    });
```

for HTML5 we can use the above code. or else just change add remove your custom attribute or do validation inside function.

Cheers !